# Limit amount of li elements shown Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

With this search function, how can i limit the amount of 'li' shown at once to 10? Also is there a way i could enable/disable filters to only show specific li elements with e.g. the class 'users'?

```
function search() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for (i = 0; i < **10**; i++) {

Comment: replacing li.length with a number messes up what elements should be shown on search

Answer (score 0):

You could add another counter (I called it `c`) to your function, which counts up to 10 whenever you find a match. If it hits 10, you don't show any more results:

```
function search() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, c;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    c = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        // only show the li, if c isn't 10 yet
        if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && c < 10) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            c++;
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but It dosen't work if there's only one letter written, any idea of why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want to display 10 items at a time. Your loop can look like:

```
for (i = idx; i < idx + 10 && i < li.length; i++) {
    some code here
}
idx += 10;
```

where idx can be a global var available across say "next" button presses. You can reset idx on page reload.